# How to solve this algorithm with [ ] ( Array notation )

Tags: actionscript-3

In the following code what's the value of a.b ? ( It's neither undefined, or null nor it is empty string )

```
var a = {} ;

a.b = [] ; 

//////////////////////a.b["hello"]="hello"; //comment, uncomment for testing it
trace( a.b )  // output is invisible, something like blank string
trace( (a.b).length ); // 0 , this could be used but the index is string ie. "hello" 

trace(a.b == undefined ) ; // false
trace(a.b == null) ; // false
```

PSEUDOCODE :

```
if ( a.b is not having any type of content inside )
{
     //How to get inside this part, when a.b is not having any value 
    // do this 
}
else
{
   //do this 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before you have just created an Array into the a Object. Array should be used to store  index base values not String one 
i.e :

`var a:Array=[]; a[0]=XXX, a[1]=YYYY;`

If you want to store String keys an Object should be used :

`var a:Object={}; a["foo"]=XXX, a["hello"]=YYYY;`

As you use an Array the length property will only reflect all the index base values you have put inside, if you have add a String base property it will not be taken into account.
What you can do is enumerate the keys of Array and break if there is at least one:

```
var isEmpty:Boolean=true;
for (var s:String in a.b) { // enumerate keys that are into a.b
 isEmpty=false;
 break; // there is at least one key so exit the loop
} 

if (isEmpty) {
     //How to get inside this part, when a.b is not having any value 
    // do this 
} else {
   //do this 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is Array.

```
a.b = [] ; 
a.b = new Array(); //is similar
```

And you can write this:

```
a.b["hello"] = 1;
```

because of Array is dynamic class. You just create field *hello*.

Comment: let's say i have a a condition that checks if "hello" is initialized or not. And suppose i didnot initialize it. Then how can i enter into the 1st block of condition ( see pseudocode )

Comment: Hm, I don't understand what you mean writing *content inside* :) If proprty is *undefined* it is means that proprty was created(`var a:Object = {}; a.b;`) but there is no any pointer to this property. If property exists and it is not *undefined* then this proprty point to some value or object.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this:
`if(a.b == null || a.b == undefined || (a.b).length == 0)`

I'm not fully understanding what you're looking to do, but wouldn't that let you know if a.b is empty?